# Cumulus as deployment tool instead of ant

Tags: apex, deployment

We want to use Cumulus instead of Ant to control our deployments. We are using Bitbucket for cv. We want to  make partial deployments in order to deploy only the changes includes in the pull request and not all the branch,also use "quick deploy" feature to decrease the time. Its possible to use Cumulus for this porpose?

We are reviewing also Solenopsis

Comment: You should also keep track of [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx) initiative.

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent writeup on CumulusCI [over here](http://developer.salesforce.org/CumulusCI/) which is also hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI) by the Salesforce Foundation. It should be enough to get you started down that path if you choose. I won't give a product recommendation, as it's really up to you to determine the most appropriate tool for your use case. However, it is likely that anyone not using Ant/Heroku/GitHub will initially be unable to take advantage of Salesforce DX, though they have stated that they hope to provide support for a number of CI and CVS systems.

Comment: Yes! We were thinking to use that one. The problem is that We dont  know if we can do partial deployments, no all the branch to decrease the deployment timmings. I can not found anything related in the documentation.

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj Salesforce DX will do this automatically, but even in ant/Jenkins it is possible to do so, you just need to do some scripting.

Comment: mmm, so maybe its better to use DX or Solenopsis or customize our Ant script instead of CumulusCI for this purpose (don't work with packages)

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj DX isn't out "yet", but should be in short order. If you can't wait, Solenopsis is probably a decent alternative.

Comment: not ready yet? mmm, also we don't want to change Intellij, maybe we need to use Force.com IDE to work with SalesforceDX

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj IntelliJ should be able to handle DX with some minor configuration. It's also likely that Intelligent Cloud for IntelliJ will support DX sometime after DX hits the market. Like I said, salesforce.com is going to give us a Heroku/Force.com IDE/GitHub experience, but we are free to modify the process as we want (e.g. Jenkins/MavensMate/GitLab, ColumbusCI/IntelliJ/Subversion)...